# CSS: How to prevent div from overlapping parent height or parent border

Tags: html, css, height

I am new to CSS and hope someone can help me with this.

I am trying to create a **simple progress bar** (for later use with JS) that contains three separate color blocks (red, yellow, green).

So far I have the below which works in general but the height of the color blocks (`class "progressBar"`) is always overlapping the parent div (`class="progressWrapper"`) by several pixels.

What **I would like to have is one bar where the color blocks just fill out its background but don't overlap it** or its border **and a visible border around the parent div**.

In my code the parent div doesn't seem to control the child divs. 
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

**My CSS (relevant parts):**

```
.bgGreen {
    background-color: green;
}
.bgRed {
    background-color: red;
}
.bgYellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.progressWrapper {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    padding: 0;
}
.progressBar {
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="col-12 progressWrapper">
    <div class="col-4 progressBar bgRed"></div>
    <div class="col-4 progressBar bgYellow"></div>
    <div class="col-4 progressBar bgGreen"></div>
</div>
```

**Update:**

```
.col-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
}
.col-12 {
    width: 100%;
}
[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Many thanks in advance, 
Mike

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with the code ? That will help to understand your  code better.

Comment: Did you try `overflow:hidden` ?

Comment: try adding some padding to `progressBar`.

Comment: @Akshay: Update: The overflow did the trick - this seems to work ! Thanks. :)

Comment: @BhanuPrakash: Thanks for this as well. I will add 1px to cover for the parent border.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This got resolved by add `overflow: hidden;` - thanks to Akshay !

Answer (score 1):

Check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/stsw92e9/)

Calculate the height of `.progressbar` by using the CSS `calc()` function, more information about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).

```
height: calc(56px / 3); /* Height of wrapper devided by number of divs */
```

Comment: Thanks for this - can you explain it ?

Comment: Sure, you calculate the width of each div inside the wrapper by deviding the full width (the one of the wrapper), by the number of divs inside of it.

Comment: Thanks but the child divs appear horizontally next to each other.

Comment: It looks like this got resolved with the suggestion from Akshay (by adding overflow: hidden).

Comment: @Thanks anyways for your help - this is good to know, too. :)